# как получить массив из функции?

Tags: c++

я недавно начал изучать c++ не судите строго

как вы уже поняли из заголовка, мне нужно получить массив из функции.
вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

int a() {
    int b[3] = { 1, 2, 3};

    return b;
}

int main() {
    int b[3] = a();

    std::cout << b[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив выделенный на стэке нельзя возвращать из функции, это неопределенное поведение.

Варианты как работать с массивом в функции:

1. передать массив как входной параметр функции
2. выделить его на куче в функции и освободить позже - не рекомендуется
3. сделать массив глобальной переменной - не рекомендуется
4. использовать stl контейнер, передавать в виде параметра или возвращать из функции - наиболее приемлемый вариант на C++

вариант с передачей массива как параметра для функции в примере ниже

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *const arr) {
  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 3;
}

int main() {
  int arr[3] = {};
  foo(arr);

  std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Или сделать массив статическим. Что, конечно, тоже имеет свои минусы.